# how to move an object on a specific path (in 2d plain like circle path around any point)using animated api in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation

when i try to set the translateX to let say some factor of translateY (2*translateX)
so that we can increase the "tranlsateY" only and object will move into certain path may be as per some equation  like ("circle","ellipse",etc.)

the question is how can we achive that here as you can see setting tranlateX to some multiplication of translateY(incase of this we are multiplying by 2) does not work so how can we achieve it in pure animated in react native...
Thank you very much your time is appreciated.

[[image: trying to use translateY value multiplied by 2 and use it for deciding translateX and it's not workingerror we are getting.].

is not usable as native method argument